# Multiple `Where()` vs. single `Where()`

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

Is:

```
var records = context.Records
                     .Where(r => r.EmployeeId == id)
                     .Where(r => r.Date >= startDate)
                     .Where(r => r.Date <= enddate)
                     .ToList();
```

Better, worse or different in anyway than:

```
var records = context.Records
                     .Where(r => r.EmployeeId == id
                            && r.Date >= startDate
                            && r.Date <= enddate)
                     .ToList();
```

The first seems easier to read, so if no difference then I would be using that to avoid using a lot of `&&`.

Comment: Just a thought, you can check the generated Entity SQL to check what difference both linq have. From Readability, second approach seems better.

Comment: I would say that readability is better with the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
var records = context.Records
                     .Where(r => r.EmployeeId == id
                            && r.Date >= startDate
                            && r.Date <= enddate)
                     .ToList();
```

is Better. Less code & save time. and Both out the same result. It is just a matter of coding style.

Comment: Additionally, the single where statement with all conditions is better because you are only iterating the collection once. The multiple where statements iterate the collection multiple times... Which is slower and uses more processing to do the same work.